# TensorFlow.js gather for string tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm new to TensorFlow.js and have a question..
When gathering elements from a list by indices

```js
const x = tf.tensor1d([32, 43, 25, 65])
const indices = tf.tensor1d([1, 3, 3], 'int32');
x.gather(indices).print();

// Tensor
//    [43, 65, 65]
```

but when x is a string tensor, it doesn't work.

```js
const x = tf.tensor1d(["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]);
const indices = tf.tensor1d([1, 3, 3], 'int32');
x.gather(indices).print();

// Uncaught Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'gather' must be numeric tensor, but got string tensor
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: string tensors are just Uint8Array-s. For now the set of operations that can be used on them is very limited. What can be done is to create a mapping between your strings to numbers and used the latter for tensors